# How to initialize a shared_ptr to a QTextCodec in my constructor?

Tags: c++, qt, std, shared-ptr

I am trying to initialize a shared_ptr to a QTextCodec (Qt class for charset conversion) in my class constructor.

This is the code I have where I get a *‘virtual QTextCodec::~QTextCodec()’ is protected within this context* error:

#### myencoder.h

```cpp
#ifndef MYENCODER_H
#define MYENCODER_H

#include <memory>
#include <QTextCodec>

class MyEncoder
{
    std::shared_ptr<QTextCodec> m_codec;

public:
    MyEncoder(QString &aCodec);
};

#endif // MYENCODER_H
```

#### myencoder.cpp

```cpp
#include "myencoder.h"

MyEncoder::MyEncoder(QString &aCodec)
{
    m_codec = std::shared_ptr<QTextCodec> (QTextCodec::codecForName(aCodec.toLatin1()));
}
```

How can I initialize my m_codec property in MyEncoder's constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [docs](https://www.copperspice.com/docs/cs_api/class_qtextcodec.html#af84836a011269c9eb67241cf8c638d83):

```
QTextCodec::~QTextCodec ( )     
                              protected virtual
```

> Destroys the QTextCodec. You should not delete codecs. Once created their lifetime becomes the responsibility of CopperSpice.

Same with the [incorporated version](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcodec.html#dtor.QTextCodec):

```
QTextCodec::~QTextCodec()               
                             [virtual protected]
```

> Destroys the QTextCodec. Note that you should not delete codecs yourself: once created they become Qt's responsibility.

So perhaps add empty deleter to your `shared_ptr` or use raw pointer and leave it up to library.

Comment: I am not using the CopperSpice libraries. I am using Qt QtextCodec. But your answer is valid to the Qt version as well.